# click anywhere to hide sliding-footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sliding footer ('`footerSlideContent`') which slides up and down (opens and closes) by clicking on a button ('`footerSlideButton`'). (The first `.js` code below shows how it works right now)

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    var open = false;
    $('#footerSlideButton, .footer_wrapper').click(function () {
        if(open === false) {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '37px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
            $("#footerSlideButton").hide(1);
            open = true;
        } else {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
            $("#footerSlideButton").show(1);
            open = false;
        }
    });     
});
```

Now I would like to be able to close the 'footerSlideContent' just by clicking anywhere on the 'document' or body. I tried this (did not work):

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    var open = false;
    $('#footerSlideButton, .footer_wrapper').click(function () {
        if(open === false) {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '37px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
            $("#footerSlideButton").hide(1);
            open = true;

        }
    });     
}); 

$(document).click.(function () {
    $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
});
```

I also tried this: (This works exactly once (ergo, I can close it by clicking anywhere on the document once), but then the 'footerSlideButton' (which is used to open the footer again) disappears...

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#footerSlideContent').length > 0 || $(e.target).closest('#footerSlideButton').length > 0) return;
    $('#footerSlideContent').slideUp(400);
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know, this version worked for me:

```
    jQuery(function($) { 
var open = false;
$('#footerSlideButton, .footer_wrapper').on('click', function () {
    if( !open ) {
        $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '37px' });
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
        $("#footerSlideButton").hide(1);
    } else {
        $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
        $("#footerSlideButton").show(1);
    }
    open = !open;
});}); 



$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#footerSlideContent').length > 0 || $(e.target).closest('#footerSlideButton').length > 0) return;
   $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
    $("#footerSlideButton").show(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to attach another click event listener to `document`. To prevent issues with overlap, compare `e.target` with the button and only fire code for the second handler if there's no overlap. **And** for the proper logic with the `open` flag, use the `.animate()` handler to run the relevant code including flipping `open`.

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    var open = false;
    $('#footerSlideButton, .footer_wrapper').on('click', function () {
        if( !open ) {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '37px' }, function() {
                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
                $("#footerSlideButton").hide(1);
                open = true;
            });
        } else {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' }, function() {
                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
                $("#footerSlideButton").show(1);
                open = false;
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click',function() {
        if( open && !$(e.target).is("#footerSlideButton") ) {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' }, function() {
                open = true;
            });
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: you're great! thanks a lot, this worked for me! As to why: because the footer is a very secondary part of my website, and I want users to be able to close it easily...

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help. Don't forget to accept this as the answer.

Comment: you could probably also do it like `$('body').on('click', function () {` but that isn't really necessary. Good answer!

Comment: hold on, I just noticed that using your solution the footer also opens on click on the document! When it's actually supposed to only close... Opening the footer should only be possible by clicking the 'footerSlideButton'. Sorry I did not check it accurately!

Comment: unfortunately not. When I use this updated code and click on 'footerSlideButton', the footer slides up and immediately slides down again... It has a similar effect like the second part of the code I posted in my question!

Comment: this new update (adding '*:not("#footerSlideButton")' ) makes total sense to me, results in exactly the same problem though.